Search in GitHub for PRs where branch protection have been bypassed
Some of our GitHub users have the option to "merge without waiting for requirements to be met". However, this is discouraged and exists for emergencies. I would like to be able to detect or search or examine PRs to see if this checkbox was checked or not.
More specifically, I would like to find all closed PRs that have been "force merged" without waiting for requirements to be met within a project.
Thank you

Do you mean programmatically or interactively? When I look at a repo's closed PRs, I see Approved, Review required, Changes requested or Draft next to the merged or closed date, maybe this is what you need? Review required and Changes requested imply the review requirements were bypassed, and next to the PR title is also the green checkmark or red X indicating if CI passed.

Either one would be fine. Interactive would be preferred. I've added a sentence to clarify. As far as I can tell, those are hints but could have false positives. For example red X appears if any checks failed, include non-required checks. I was hoping GitHub records the value of the checkbox somewhere so I can query it directly.

This script checks the statuses of merged PRs and finds forced merges.
For now it check both - the merge commit, and the last commit on the PR's source branch.
It also check both status checks and check runs. You can update the script for remove unneeded checks.
import os
import logging
from github import Github

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Read GitHub token, organization, and repository name from env varibles
token = os.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
owner = os.getenv("GITHUB_OWNER")
repo_name = os.getenv("GITHUB_REPO")

logger.info("GitHub token and repository details retrieved from environment variables.")

# Authenticate
g = Github(token)

def find_force_merged_prs(owner, repo_name):
    logger.info(f"Searching for force merged PRs in repository: {owner}/{repo_name}")
    repo = g.get_repo(f"{owner}/{repo_name}")
    closed_prs = repo.get_pulls(state="closed")
    force_merged_prs = []

    for pr in closed_prs:
        logger.info(f"Checking PR #{pr.number}: {pr.title}")

        if pr.merged_at:
            logger.info(f"PR #{pr.number} is merged. Checking commit statuses and check runs.")

            # Check both the merge commit and the last commit on the PR branch
            merge_commit_sha = pr.merge_commit_sha
            head_commit_sha = pr.head.sha

            # Function to check commit statuses and check runs for a given commit SHA
            def check_commit_status_and_runs(commit_sha):
                commit = repo.get_commit(commit_sha)

                # Check Commit Statuses
                combined_status = commit.get_combined_status()
                statuses = combined_status.statuses
                has_failed_statuses = any(
                    status.state in ["failure", "pending"] for status in statuses
                )

                # Log statuses
                if statuses:
                    logger.info(f"Found {len(statuses)} statuses for commit {commit_sha}")
                    for status in statuses:
                        logger.info(f"Status Context: {status.context}, State: {status.state}")
                else:
                    logger.info(f"No statuses found for commit {commit_sha}.")

                # Check Check Runs (GitHub Actions or other Checks API integrations)
                check_runs = commit.get_check_runs()
                has_failed_runs = any(
                    run.conclusion in ["failure", "cancelled", "timed_out"] or run.status == "in_progress"
                    for run in check_runs
                )

                # Log check runs
                if check_runs.totalCount > 0:
                    logger.info(f"Found {check_runs.totalCount} check runs for commit {commit_sha}")
                    for run in check_runs:
                        logger.info(f"Check Run: {run.name}, Status: {run.status}, Conclusion: {run.conclusion}")
                else:
                    logger.info(f"No check runs found for commit {commit_sha}.")

                # true if either statuses or check runs have failed or are pending
                return has_failed_statuses or has_failed_runs

            # Check the merge commit first, then fall back to the PR's head commit
            has_failed_or_pending_checks = check_commit_status_and_runs(merge_commit_sha)
            if not has_failed_or_pending_checks:
                logger.info(f"Falling back to checking last commit on PR branch for PR #{pr.number}.")
                has_failed_or_pending_checks = check_commit_status_and_runs(head_commit_sha)

            # Record the PR if there are failed or pending statuses or check runs
            if has_failed_or_pending_checks:
                logger.warning(f"PR #{pr.number} was force merged without all checks passing.")
                force_merged_prs.append(pr)
            else:
                logger.info(f"PR #{pr.number} passed all required checks before merging.")
        else:
            logger.info(f"PR #{pr.number} was closed but not merged.")

    logger.info("Completed search for force merged PRs.")
    return force_merged_prs

force_merged_prs = find_force_merged_prs(owner, repo_name)
logger.info("Force Merged PRs:")
for pr in force_merged_prs:
    logger.info(f"- PR #{pr.number}: {pr.title} (merged at {pr.merged_at})")

